# class.forName, looking for a class in a different project, throws ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse

In eclipse I've got 2 different project : ProjectX, generic and projectA specific.

In projectX :

```
 public static final Plugin getPlugin(String sIdentifier ) {
     String sPluginClassName = "packageName.blabla.ClassName";
     try {
                pluginClass = Class.forName(sClassName);
    ...
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                throw new BusinessException(sIdentifier, e);
    }
}
```

in projectA :

```
package packageName.blabla;

public class ClassName () {
 ....
}
```

During execution I get a BusinessException due to ClassNotFoundException. The class path is ok (copy/pasted not written). In eclipse projectA java build path / libraries contains projectX folder, projectX build path hasn't got any reference to projectA (seems legit).

This works fine in  a projectB specific interaction with ProjectX (I don't know where are
 the differences : I've checked both build path, it's done the same way).

Any idea?

Comment: I think your library/references are the wrong way around.  In your ProjectX you are loading class from ProjectA, therefore it needs to have ProjectA referenced.

Comment: It means your class did not loaded

Comment: Aleks G is right. The reference should be the other way.

Answer (score 4):

> projectX build path hasn't got any reference to projectA (seems legit).

While you don't need a build-time dependency of projectX on projectA, the "bin" directory for projectA needs to be on the execution classpath for projectX.  If it isn't, then the call to `Class.forName` in `getPlugin` won't look at the "projectA/bin" directory, and won't find the class that it is trying to load.

---

The execution classpath can be configured via the "Run > Run Configurations" window.

- Select the run config for your application.
- Go to the Classpath panel
- Select User Classpath
- Click on "Add Projects" and select the project you want to add.
- Apply the configuration change.

Comment: how do you change the execution classpath on eclipse ? I've added the projectA/bin folder using projectX >properties > java build path > add class folder and I still have the same error. Did I do it the wrong way ?